# How do I flip a Tensor in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, flip, tensor

For example: I have a tensor with shape `(5,10)` and I want back a tensor with shape `(5,10)` but the first element should now be the last element. so `[1,2,3,4,5]`becomes `[5,4,3,2,1]` and `[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6]]` becomes `[[2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5]]`.

If it matter, I am using tensorflow backend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [Keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/), there is the `reverse` function.

```
import keras.backend as K

flipped = K.reverse(x,axes=0)
```

For using it in a layer, you can create a Lambda layer:

```
from keras.layers import *
layer = Lambda(lambda x: K.reverse(x,axes=0),output_shape=(shape of x))
```

(If it's a sequential layer, `model.add(layer)`, if a functional API model, `output = layer(input)`

Comment: How would I go about implementing this as a layer?

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: You're my hero!

Comment: By the way, maybe you should use `axes=1`. Because `0` is the batch dimension, it will invert your example sequence. `1` is the first dimension of what you usually define in keras, it will invert the first dimension of **each example**.  (Keras doesn't demand you to define the batch size in shapes).

Comment: How to view the flipped tensor ? when I try to print, ti just gives : `<tf.Tensor 'ReverseV2_10:0' shape=(10000, 16, 71) dtype=float32>`

Comment: Usually you create a submodel that outputs that layer and predict it with input data. If this is not part of a model, you could try `K.eval(tensor)`.